# How to publish Android application with SQLServer database (Web Services) on Play Store?

Tags: android, sql-server, publishing

I want to publish my application on Play Store but I have a problem: I developed my application in Android Studio using SQL Server database using Web Services (WCF). Now I want to publish it and I dont know how to publish an application with SQL server database. Kindly complete guide me. Thanks

Comment: you publish it 100% same way as any other app. Only extra thing is that you need to make sure that the users are able to access your database from the internet

Comment: Sir how the users will get my database because i am not using Sq-lite i am using SQL Server database, kindly guide me please.

Comment: user will not get your database, you need to place it on your server, to which your app will connect for data

Comment: Thank you so much sir it much helpful, but  how i will connect  app with that database? and whats about visual studio coding (Web Services) where i will place web services?

Comment: how do you connect it now?

Comment: yes sir its my question, how i will connect it?

Comment: Nom that is my question: How is it connected currently?

Comment: i am using this app offline by making my laptop as a server, i installed SQlserver, visual studio and Android studio, i am using my laptop as a server and data shows on my mobile screen retrieved from sql server database,

Comment: you have to move it to the real server, so it is available through the internet, or make your laptop available from the internet

Comment: ok sir thank you so much, should i move my visual studio code as wel? or only database?

Comment: have no idea, depends on the code itself

Comment: ok sir thank you :-)